# Touchscreen not showing on Xinput

Tags: linux-mint, drivers, hardware, xinput, touch-screen

**Disclaimer**: I am a relative novice and am hoping I just don't know how to interpret what I am seeing onto my device.

**Problem and *context***: I got a Windows surface PRO and it was indefensibly slow, but the touchscreen did work. Thought to myself *"You know what, this is a perfect time to try Linux! You have been promising yourself this for a long time." ... and it worked like a charm! *mostly!* The touchscreen won't show up at all! I followed the [Arch Linux Wiki Touchscreen page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Touchscreen) but it didn't fix my problem. I am terribly worried I will break something and I will not be able to fix it!

***Running Edits***:

-Unknown dsi-1 Shows as display if that helps

-Broke up the info visually so it was less headache inducing

**All the Info I can think of**:

Linux Mint 20 "Ulyana" - Cinnamon 64-bit (Fresh install)

---

System:    Kernel: 5.4.0-40-generic x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: gcc v: 9.3.0 Desktop: Cinnamon 4.6.6
wm: muffin dm: LightDM Distro: Linux Mint 20 Ulyana base: Ubuntu 20.04 focal

---

Machine:   Type: Detachable System: RCA product: W122SC24T3 v: N/A serial: 
Mobo: RCA model: WT9S12WL00 serial:  UEFI: American Megatrends
v: BSR3ELUS-W122T3-RCA-V13 date: 06/28/2018

---

Battery:   ID-1: BAT0 charge: 17.5 Wh condition: 24.3/24.3 Wh (100%) volts: 7.4/N/A
model: GLK MRD Li-ion Battery serial:  status: Charging

---

CPU:       Topology: Dual Core model: Intel Celeron N4000 bits: 64 type: MCP arch: Goldmont Plus
rev: 1 L2 cache: 4096 KiB
flags: lm nx pae sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 ssse3 vmx bogomips: 4377
Speed: 2577 MHz min/max: 800/2600 MHz Core speeds (MHz): 1: 2576 2: 2487

---

Graphics:  Device-1: Intel UHD Graphics 605 driver: i915 v: kernel bus ID: 00:02.0
chip ID: 8086:3185
Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.20.8 driver: modesetting unloaded: fbdev,vesa
resolution: 1920x1200~50Hz
OpenGL: renderer: Mesa Intel UHD Graphics 600 (GLK 2) v: 4.6 Mesa 20.0.8
direct render: Yes

---

Audio:     Device-1: Intel vendor: Realtek driver: snd_hda_intel v: kernel bus ID: 00:0e.0
chip ID: 8086:3198
Sound Server: ALSA v: k5.4.0-40-generic

---

Network:   Message: No Device data found.
Device-1: Realtek 802.11n WLAN Adapter type: USB driver: btusb,rtl8xxxu bus ID: 1-4:3
chip ID: 0bda:b720
IF: wlx58b3fc225ea9 state: up mac:

---

Drives:    Local Storage: total: 58.24 GiB used: 18.24 GiB (31.3%)
ID-1: /dev/mmcblk0 model: DF4064 size: 58.24 GiB serial:

---

Partition: ID-1: / size: 56.58 GiB used: 18.23 GiB (32.2%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/mmcblk0p2

---

USB:       Hub: 1-0:1 info: Full speed (or root) Hub ports: 9 rev: 2.0 chip ID: 1d6b:0002
Device-1: 1-3:2 info: Realtek RTS5129 Card Reader Controller type: 
driver: rtsx_usb,rtsx_usb_ms,rtsx_usb_sdmmc rev: 2.0 chip ID: 0bda:0129
Device-2: 1-4:3 info: Realtek 802.11n WLAN Adapter type: Bluetooth
driver: btusb,rtl8xxxu rev: 2.1 chip ID: 0bda:b720
Device-3: 1-7:5 info: Realtek USB Camera type: Video driver: uvcvideo rev: 2.0
chip ID: 0bda:2538
Device-4: 1-8:6 info: Realtek USB Camera type: Video driver: uvcvideo rev: 2.0
chip ID: 0bda:7648

---

```
beth@Ruusu:~$ xinput list
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Keyboard K850 Consumer Control            id=19   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ M585/M590 Mouse                           id=26   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ USB Camera: Front-facing camera           id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ USB Camera: Main Camera                   id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Intel HID events                          id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Intel HID 5 button array                  id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=14   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Keyboard K850 Keyboard                    id=17   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Keyboard K850 System Control              id=18   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Keyboard K850 Consumer Control            id=20   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ M585/M590 Keyboard                        id=25   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

---

```
I: Bus=0019 Vendor=0000 Product=0005 Version=0000
N: Name="Lid Switch"
P: Phys=PNP0C0D/button/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0A08:00/device:03/PNP0C09:00/PNP0C0D:00/input/input0
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=event0 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=21
B: SW=1

I: Bus=0019 Vendor=0000 Product=0001 Version=0000
N: Name="Power Button"
P: Phys=PNP0C0C/button/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0C0C:00/input/input1
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=kbd event1 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=3
B: KEY=10000000000000 0

I: Bus=0011 Vendor=0001 Product=0001 Version=ab83
N: Name="AT Translated Set 2 keyboard"
P: Phys=isa0060/serio0/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/platform/i8042/serio0/input/input2
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=sysrq kbd event2 leds 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=120013
B: KEY=402000000 3803078f800d001 feffffdfffefffff fffffffffffffffe
B: MSC=10
B: LED=7

I: Bus=0019 Vendor=0000 Product=0006 Version=0000
N: Name="Video Bus"
P: Phys=LNXVIDEO/video/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0A08:00/LNXVIDEO:00/input/input3
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=kbd event3 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=3
B: KEY=3e000b00000000 0 0 0

I: Bus=0019 Vendor=0000 Product=0000 Version=0000
N: Name="Intel HID events"
P: Phys=
S: Sysfs=/devices/platform/INT33D5:00/input/input24
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=rfkill kbd event6 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=13
B: KEY=81000300000000 5000004000 1e294000000020 0
B: MSC=10

I: Bus=0019 Vendor=0000 Product=0000 Version=0000
N: Name="Intel HID 5 button array"
P: Phys=
S: Sysfs=/devices/platform/INT33D5:00/input/input25
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=kbd event7 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=13
B: KEY=2000000000000 0 0 0 0 1000000000000 0 201c000000000000 0
B: MSC=10

I: Bus=0003 Vendor=0bda Product=2538 Version=0107
N: Name="USB Camera: Front-facing camera"
P: Phys=usb-0000:00:15.0-7/button
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:15.0/usb1/1-7/1-7:1.0/input/input26
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=kbd event8 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=3
B: KEY=100000 0 0 0

I: Bus=0003 Vendor=0bda Product=7648 Version=0105
N: Name="USB Camera: Main Camera"
P: Phys=usb-0000:00:15.0-8/button
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:15.0/usb1/1-8/1-8:1.0/input/input27
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=kbd event9 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=3
B: KEY=100000 0 0 0

I: Bus=0000 Vendor=0000 Product=0000 Version=0000
N: Name="HDA Intel PCH Mic"
P: Phys=ALSA
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:0e.0/sound/card0/input28
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=event10 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=21
B: SW=10

I: Bus=0000 Vendor=0000 Product=0000 Version=0000
N: Name="HDA Intel PCH Front Headphone"
P: Phys=ALSA
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:0e.0/sound/card0/input29
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=event11 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=21
B: SW=4

I: Bus=0000 Vendor=0000 Product=0000 Version=0000
N: Name="HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=3"
P: Phys=ALSA
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:0e.0/sound/card0/input30
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=event12 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=21
B: SW=140

I: Bus=0000 Vendor=0000 Product=0000 Version=0000
N: Name="HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=7"
P: Phys=ALSA
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:0e.0/sound/card0/input31
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=event13 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=21
B: SW=140

I: Bus=0000 Vendor=0000 Product=0000 Version=0000
N: Name="HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=8"
P: Phys=ALSA
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:0e.0/sound/card0/input32
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=event14 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=21
B: SW=140
: Bus=0000 Vendor=0000 Product=0000 Version=0000
N: Name="HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=9"
P: Phys=ALSA
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:0e.0/sound/card0/input33
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=event15 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=21
B: SW=140

I: Bus=0000 Vendor=0000 Product=0000 Version=0000
N: Name="HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=10"
P: Phys=ALSA
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:0e.0/sound/card0/input34
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=event16 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=21
B: SW=140

I: Bus=0005 Vendor=046d Product=b34d Version=0015
N: Name="Keyboard K850 Keyboard"
P: Phys=58:b3:fc:25:6b:e9
S: Sysfs=/devices/virtual/misc/uhid/0005:046D:B34D.0006/input/input35
U: Uniq=ca:b0:bf:53:23:4a
H: Handlers=sysrq kbd event17 leds 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=120013
B: KEY=1000000000007 ff800000000007ff febeffdfffefffff fffffffffffffffe
B: MSC=10
B: LED=1f

I: Bus=0005 Vendor=046d Product=b34d Version=0015
N: Name="Keyboard K850 Consumer Control"
P: Phys=58:b3:fc:25:6b:e9
S: Sysfs=/devices/virtual/misc/uhid/0005:046D:B34D.0006/input/input36
U: Uniq=ca:b0:bf:53:23:4a
H: Handlers=kbd event18 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=1f
B: KEY=300ff 0 0 483ffff17aff32d bfd4444600000000 1 130ff38b17c000 677bfad9415fed 9ed68000004400 10000002
B: REL=1040
B: ABS=100000000
B: MSC=10

I: Bus=0005 Vendor=046d Product=b34d Version=0015
N: Name="Keyboard K850 System Control"
P: Phys=58:b3:fc:25:6b:e9
S: Sysfs=/devices/virtual/misc/uhid/0005:046D:B34D.0006/input/input37
U: Uniq=ca:b0:bf:53:23:4a
H: Handlers=kbd event19 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=13
B: KEY=c000 10000000000000 0
B: MSC=10

I: Bus=0005 Vendor=046d Product=b01b Version=0011
N: Name="M585/M590 Keyboard"
P: Phys=58:b3:fc:25:6b:e9
S: Sysfs=/devices/virtual/misc/uhid/0005:046D:B01B.0009/input/input44
U: Uniq=d9:9b:a6:6f:c6:c1
H: Handlers=sysrq kbd event24 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=100013
B: KEY=1000000000007 ff800000000007ff febeffdfffefffff fffffffffffffffe
B: MSC=10

I: Bus=0005 Vendor=046d Product=b01b Version=0011
N: Name="M585/M590 Mouse"
P: Phys=58:b3:fc:25:6b:e9
S: Sysfs=/devices/virtual/misc/uhid/0005:046D:B01B.0009/input/input45
U: Uniq=d9:9b:a6:6f:c6:c1
H: Handlers=mouse2 event25 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=17
B: KEY=ffff0000 0 0 0 0
B: REL=1943
B: MSC=10

(END)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just FYI, in case this helps someone else:

Remove the touchscreen's kernel module:

```
sudo modprobe -r i2c_hid
```

Then, reload it:

```
sudo modprobe i2c_hid
```

Source: Reddit - [No touchscreen after surface-kernel installation (Surface Go, Ubuntu)](https://www.reddit.com/r/SurfaceLinux/comments/ehrpe6/no_touchscreen_after_surfacekernel_installation/)